# How can I revert my etc/postfix/main.cf file?

Tags: macos

I've already lost my etc/postfix/main.cf file in Yosemite. Could someone help me to revert or give me the link to download it?

Answer (score 2):

If you've manipulated your main.cf already, check your backups to recover it.

Otherwise simply copy the default file: main.cf.default:

```
sudo copy /etc/postfix/main.cf.default /etc/postfix/main.cf
```

and replace the last two lines with:

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix
inet_protocols = all
message_size_limit = 10485760
mailbox_size_limit = 0
biff = no
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, [::1]/128
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated permit
recipient_delimiter = +
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_ciphers = medium
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
```

Comment: Also - Apple publishes this file on their open source site: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=main.cf+site:opensource.apple.com and before making further changes, consider enabling a local time machine and snapshotting things: `sudo tmutil enablelocal && tmutil snapshot`

Comment: Thank for your all supports. I will going on with your helps.